# Is it possible to use icon packs with the ASUS launcher?

Tags: icon-packs

I have a DigiLand tablet that I have downloaded and it runs the so-called "ASUS" launcher. I had downloaded many icon packs before my switch to this launcher. I am wondering, if it is possible to use icon packs, how do I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the descriptions of the icon packs is usually specified for which launcher these can be used. (Not every Icon Pack is compatible with every launcher)

Most preinstalled launcher do not provide support for icon packs at all. If you want to use icon pack you have to read the description and change to a corresponding launcher.